# Add and replace data ListBoxes (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm very new to Visual Studio. I want to create a currency converter, using Listboxes. But now i'm stuck with this program.
I have multiple cases in my Listbox. This program works as follow:

1. The user selects a valuta in Listbox "ListboxMunteenheden"
2. The program show a InputBox. The user enters a number in the InputBox
3. The selected item will be added in the Listbox "ListBoxWisselkoersen" and 
   if it is applicable, the value in "ListBoxWisselkoersen" will be replaced.

I don't get the last point working. The selected item won't appear in ListboxWisselkoersen, and I don't get the old data replaced either.

Can anyone help me with this function?

```
Private Sub ListBoxMunteenheden_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBoxMunteenheden.SelectedIndexChanged

'De Cases worden aangemaakt om de verschillende Munteenheden aan ListBox Wisselkoersen toe te voegen.

   Select Case ListBoxMunteenheden.SelectedIndex

      Case 0
         'De Amerikaanse Dollar wordt toegevoegd aan ListBoxWisselkoersen
          Dim AmerikaanseDollar As Decimal
          AmerikaanseDollar = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers >0 en <500 voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Euro = .... Amerikaanse Dollar):  ")

          For i = 0 To ListBoxWisselkoersen.Items.Count - 1
              ' Er wordt gezocht in de tekst van de valuta en vervangen hem met de nieuwe waarde.
              If InStr(ListBoxWisselkoersen.Items(i), "Amerikaanse Dollar") > 0 Then
                  ListBoxWisselkoersen.Items(i) = "1 Euro =  " & AmerikaanseDollar.ToString & "  Amerikaanse Dollar"

              Else
              End If
              If AmerikaanseDollar <= 0 Or AmerikaanseDollar >= 500 Then
                   MsgBox("U dient een andere waarde op te geven, tussen de 1 en 499.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
                   'Er wordt gecontroleerd of de waarde tussen de 0 en de 500 ligt. Als de MessageBox hieraan voldoet, zal de functie uitgevoerd worden.

              End If
          Next
```

Comment: I can't see any code to 'add' the valuta selected in the first list box to the second one.

Comment: I used this string to add the data:  If InStr(ListBoxWisselkoersen.Items(i), "Amerikaanse Dollar") > 0 Then
                  ListBoxWisselkoersen.Items(i) = "1 Euro =  " & AmerikaanseDollar.ToString & "  Amerikaanse Dollar"

Comment: I also tried it with this string (much simpler) . But then i couldn't delete this string after someone tries to replace it with a new amount.                                                                                                            
    Case 2
Dim BritsePonden As Decimal
BritsePonden = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers >0 en <500 voor de Euro tov Britse Ponden (1 Euro = .... Britse Ponden)")
 ListBoxWisselkoersen.Items.Add("1 Euro =  " & BritsePonden.ToString & " Britse Ponden")